# Parse.com - using only emails for user login

Tags: authentication, parse-platform

With the default login and signup views provided by Parse, can I avoid asking the users to choose a username and just use email as user identifier?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[By Parse support team]
You can change the Placeholder label on the username field to say "Email Address", and you can hide the normal Email address field on the Login View Controller.

Answer (score 2):

```
signUpController.signUpView.emailAsUsername = true
```

Comment: Hi eric does this removes the username request? the question was about only asking for an email and not a username

Comment: This answer is most correct now with the new Parse SDKs